# MySql 5.7 installer fails to detect VS 2013 redistributable

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2016

Trying to install the latest version of MySQL Server - 5.7.19 - on a clean Windows server machine using the MySql installer MSI package.

On first attempt it told me it needed a prerequisite of the Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable and installed it. When trying to install the server, however, it then complains:

> 1: Action 10:59:21: INSTALL.
>
> 1: 1: MySQL Server 5.7 2: {F08E9C75-A42E-4962-8760-4CBD9CF35D7A}
>
> 1: Action 10:59:21: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related
>   applications
>
> 1: Action 10:59:21: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
>
> 1: Action 10:59:21: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
>
> 1: This application requires Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable.
>   Please install  the Redistributable then run this installer again.
>
> 1: 1: MySQL Server 5.7 2: {F08E9C75-A42E-4962-8760-4CBD9CF35D7A} 3: 3
>
> 1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 5.7.19' failed.

I've tried rebooting the machine - problem persists.

I've checked in the registry to ensure Windows knows the package is installed, which it does.

I've tried installing the previous version of MySql and that installs fine.

So I cleaned out all the installations and re-ran the package, this time also selecting Workbench, Shell and some other useful tools. All of it installed fine - except the Server. That's still demanding the redistributable which is already installed.

Where can I go from here?

Comment: Try installing 32 bit version of MySQL! Worked for me.

Comment: I tried Heiko Ebens's solution today (13th Jan 2018) and it worked perfectly. I recommend trying that before anything else.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I had the same issue today while installing MySQL 5.7 and not sure how shall I proceed and found your questions. I was sure that I have installed the 64bit version of Visual C++ Redistributable Packages on my machine. Then I installed a 32-bit version of the same package (URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784) and the MySQL Installer detected that and proceed with the installation.

Looks like the installer was looking for 32bit install path. Hope this help.

Comment: So this is a case of Oracle installer being Oracle installer - a mess.

Comment: Try this link for various versions https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: I did try to select both options (x64+x86) at once and install then both but for some reason that is not the same as installing just x86 version of VS2013 Redistributable. Thank you for this!

Comment: I also faced the same problem but after installing the 32bit (initially installed 64 bit) it worked like a charm.

Comment: My intention was to install x64, but I encountered this same problem. So I selected the x86 server, I installed the redistribution c++ for x86 and clicked back. After that, I selected the correct x64 installation and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Looks strange (As i am installing it on 64bit machine) but solution working.

Comment: Thanks..saved a whole lot of time

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue while installing MySQL 5.7.19 where I was installing the x64 version of visual C++ redistributable and it refused to work. Eventually was able to get around it in a similar way to Prabhat, but installed the x86 version instead. Working so far.

Would have commented this on Prabhat's answer, but reputation restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

For a 64-bit MySQL server installation, I suggest updating the 64-bit version of the Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable Package (in my case from 12.0.30501 to 12.0.40660); the Redistributable Package update can found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3179560/update-for-visual-c-2013-and-visual-c-redistributable-package).  I came across this solution [on this MySQL Forum post](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?169,659133,659152#msg-659152), but used the answer by [Prabhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050262/prabhat) (on a different server) before and it worked too.

Comment: The work-around to install the latest updated 2013 redist worked like a charm, Heiko. I did not have to install the x86 version. Thanks!

Comment: Many Thanks! This worked for me too (legacy application...), no need to install the 32 bit version. Great!

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue, I tried multiple times, even removed multiple version of the Visual Studio Redistribute 2013, but MySql V5.7 didn't get install. I tried both x86 and 64 bit, but result was same.

**Solution:**
I have downloaded MySql Version **5.6** instead of 5.7, then its gets installed like a charm.

**Note:**

Seems like there must be some issue with the MySql V 5.7 installer.

Comment: This is not a solution at all.
MySQL 5.7 and 5.6 are different, 5.7 has new features that are missing in 5.6 and some things have been deprecated. So, if your server/app uses them (newer or older) you can't replace 5.7 with 5.6.

What's new: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-additions
Other things: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/added-removed-variables-options.html

Comment: Try the above solution. I am also facing the same issue after installation of VS Redistribute 2013 for my Mysql Server 5.7 64 bit. Then I also installed VS Redistribute 2013 32 bit. And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem installing MySQL 5.7.19 because installation claimed C++ Redistributable 2013 not installed when both 16 and 32 bit version were already installed.  None of the other answers here worked for me.

What I discovered is that after repairing my C++ Redistributable, the installer then found it.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the solutions posted by users in this thread, both solutions (either installing runtime for both architectures 32 and 64 bits or installing a newer version of runtime) work.

The better solution is to install the newer version of [VC++ 2013 x64 runtime](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/6/056dcda9-d667-4e27-8001-8a0c6971d6b1/vcredist_x64.exe). Please make sure you are installing the one with a file version of `12.0.40660.0` as the one the MySQL Installer currently installs is version `12.0.30501.0`, and any with this or lower version may cause errors. Thanks to Jafeth Carrillo Salas for the best solution, and to all other users that contributed with other workarounds.

We will fix this issue using the newer runtime version, you can track the status at [this MySQL bug link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87962).

Answer (score 0):

My computer system language is Chinese.
At first,i install English version of visual c++ 2013 , it can't work.
And than, i uninstall visual c++ 2013(en). install visual c++ 2013(cn).
it works.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to install the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013, doesn't matter if you have installed the ones of 2015 for some reason. Install both x86 and x64 versions. Here's the  [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) to the installers. Hope it works for you, it did for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try following steps:

**step 1.** Got to https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784

[image]

**step 2.** Click for downloading ***Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013***

**step 3.** Check **vcredist_x64.exe** for 64 bit or **vcredist_x86.exe** for 32 bit

[image]

**step 4.** Click next and after downloading Install vcredist_** in your machine

After then relaunch **MySQL installer** and repeat the mysql installation process.

Comment: x64 installer doesn't work with MySQL; hence the question. You need to install x86 as the answer.