# MySQL 5.7.19 not installing. Giving same error

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

I have been trying to install MYSQL 5.7.19 but it gives me the following error while installing the "MYSQL SERVER 5.7.19" although the rest of the things are installed perfectly.

```
1: Action 14:02:10: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Server 5.7 2: {EC09D203-422B-4C9F-B623-230EF57EE709} 
1: Action 14:02:10: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 14:02:10: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 14:02:10: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: This application requires Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable. Please install the Redistributable then run this installer again.
1: 1: MySQL Server 5.7 2: {EC09D203-422B-4C9F-B623-230EF57EE709} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 5.7.19' failed.
```

After this, I installed the "VISUAL C++ Redistributable 2013" as I could not find the "Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable". First thing I want to ask is are these two the same? If not then where to find the "Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable". After installing the "VISUAL C++ Redistributable 2013", I still get the same error. Another thing is, if I don't install 'MySQL Server 5.7.19' and let it fail, will my MySQL not work properly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This happened to me as well today actually.
What you need to do is to install the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013, doesn't matter if you have installed the ones of 2015 for some reason. Install both x86 and x64 versions. Here's the  [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) to the installers. Hope it works for you, it did for me.

Comment: Install both x86 and x64 versions. <- that is the main point. Really tricky ><"

Comment: I installed the x86 first and the x64 afterwards which gave me an option to Repair as if it was already there. I Repaired and that fixed it for me

Answer (score 16):

Simple workaround (there's a bug in msi install sequence file):

- download and install the server through the web installer and let it failed
- open C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Product Cache\mysql-5.7.20-winx64.exe or download msi installer from CDN (you can take the correct url from the installer logs)
- install the mysql-5.7.20-winx64.exe but exclude "Server Data Files"
- re-run the web installer and click "Quick Action / Reconfigure" and configure you mysql instance
- add the required packages

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Still the same issue with the mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.11.0.msi installer

Comment: Worked successfully for installer 5.7. Thanks man!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with **MySQL Server 5.7.19 x64**.

I installed **Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable x64** but it does not works, so you have to install **Update for Visual C++ 2013 and Visual C++ Redistributable Package**
wich can be found here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3179560/update-for-visual-c-2013-and-visual-c-redistributable-package.

With this solution you can install v5.7 instead of v5.6.

Credits goes for **Jafeth Carrillo Salas**, https://forums.mysql.com/profile.php?169,11205311

Answer (score 3):

This seems duplicate of [MySql 5.7 installer fails to detect VS 2013 redistributable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163588/mysql-5-7-installer-fails-to-detect-vs-2013-redistributable).
I had a same issue, I tried multiple times, even removed multiple version of the Visual Studio Redistribute 2013, but MySql V5.7 didn't get install. I tried both x86 and 64 bit, but result was same.

**Solution:** I have downloaded MySql Version 5.6 instead of 5.7, then its gets installed like a charm.

**Note:**

Seems like there must be some issue with the MySql V 5.7 installer.

Comment: Well, I'll also try it then. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Simple workaround (there's a bug in msi install sequence file):

download and install the server through the web installer and let it failed
open C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Product Cache\mysql-5.7.20-winx64.exe or download msi installer from CDN (you can take the correct url from the installer logs)
install the mysql-5.7.20-winx64.exe but exclude "Server Data Files"
re-run the web installer and click "Quick Action / Reconfigure" and configure you mysql instance
add the required packages

Thanks. It works for me.!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can find answers to your question at the install instructions at [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html). To install the server you need the Visual Studio C++ 2013 Redistributable, which you can find at [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784).

If your MySQL will work properly, if you don't install the server depends on your needs. If you just connect to another server somewhere else I don't see any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Remove mysql server and install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages 32bit and 64bit both version after that resolve the issue.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784
vcredist_x64.exe
vcredist_x86.exe

Comment: No this will not help.