# Troubleshoot Installing MySql 8.0 and Visual C++ Redistributable on Windows

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

When installing [MySql 8.0 Installer for Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html), I get the following error:

> This application requires Visual Studio 2015 x64 Redistributable.
>   Please install the Redistributable then run this installer again.

The error message seems to actually refer to the Visual **C++** Redistributable per the [install prerequisites](https://dev.mysql.com/resources/wb62_prerequisites.html).  When I download the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145), I get this error:

> VS 2015 C++ Redistributable Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed

How can I fix this?

This is the 8.0 update to [this question on installing MySQL 5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45163588/1366033) which seems to face a similar set of issues

Answer (score 6):

Asking and answering because googling this turns up very little and it's a non-obvious solution and affecting a major release.

If Visual Studio 2017 is installed, it'll come with the 2017 C++ Redistributable, but there's a bug which prevents the installation of previous versions.  So, per [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/14701/visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2015-ca.html) you must:

1. Uninstall the Visual C++ Redistributable **2017**
2. Install the [Visual C++ Redistributable **2015**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53840)
3. Install MySql
4. Re-install the [Visual C++ Redistributable **2017**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

It can sometimes be hard to locate the Redistributable from "Add or Remove Programs".  If that's the case, you can find in `C:/ProgramData/Package Cache`:

```bash
$ find "C:/ProgramData/Package Cache" -name "VC_redist.*.exe"
```

Then call `/uninstall` on both locations:

```bash
"C:/ProgramData/Package Cache/{427ada59-85e7-4bc8-b8d5-ebf59db60423}/VC_redist.x64.exe" /uninstall
"C:/ProgramData/Package Cache/{67f67547-9693-4937-aa13-56e296bd40f6}/VC_redist.x86.exe" /uninstall
```

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2017 installed, and did not need to uninstall the VC 2015 redistributable; simply installing the redistributable from the 2017 URL worked. (on that page, it mentions that the download is for VC 2015-2019; maybe it's a new package since KyleMit's original post?) anyway, I thought I'd mention this, since it might save some time.

Comment: I can confirm the comment. I just did step 4 and that worked.